# Flutter: Undefined name Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing a few strange issues with Flutter. I do have very little knowledge about Flutter. I am learning it.

```
class ViewOtherProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  final String userName;
  final int points;

  const ViewOtherProfile({
    @required this.userName,
    @required this.points,
  });
```

You can see i am getting userName and Points data as argument. 
I want to print this argument in the page. Like this

```
class _ViewOtherProfileState extends State<ViewOtherProfile> {
..........

void initState(){ 
print(points);

     deviceInfo();
    super.initState();
     print(userName);
    ]);
   } 
    ............
```

Now problem is i am getting error.

```
Undefined name 'userName'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
```

Any reason why i am getting this error and how i can resolve it.

**Thanks to @jamesdlin**

I tried to put it like this

```
print(ViewOtherProfile.userName);
```

but now i am getting another error.

```
Instance member 'userName' can't be accessed using static access.
```

Comment: `userName` is a  member of `ViewOtherProfile`, not a member of `_ViewOtherProfileState`.  You can access it from `_ViewOtherProfileState` by using `widget.userName`.

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks for the suggestion any example would be very helpful. i don't undertstand about widget.userName.

Comment: What jamesdlin is saying is that *userName* is a part of the widget, which is *ViewOtherProfile*, not the state object(_ViewOtherProfileState). In order to use  *userName* in the state object you procure it from the widget by doing  *widget.userName*

Comment: @Unbreachable Thanks for the clarification. I tried print(ViewOtherProfile.userName); but now i can see error on Print and userName. Instance member 'userName' can't be accessed using static access.

Comment: No, *ViewOtherProfile.userName* is incorrect. *ViewOtherProfile* *is* the stateful widget itself with the properties you declared. It's been already clarified that you use it like this *widget.userName*

Comment: @Unbreachable  i tried that too but no luck. Still getting error. Error - Expected to find ']'.  i tried this print(widget.userName);

Comment: That is a different situation

Comment: `print(userName);
    ]);` should be `print(userName);
    });` Notice the replacement of `]` with `}` Just a syntax error

Comment: @Unbreachable Ideally it shouldn't be part of Init.State. Same is working fine if i used it in a function. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main types of widgets in Flutter. `StatelessWidget` and `StatefullWidget`. A StatelessWidget is built only one when the UI builds and is never rebuilt. Meanwhile, a StatefulWidget can be rebuilt every time if a call for `setState` is made.

Hence, for a StatefulWiget, there is a need to track the state of the class by extending the main class with a `State` class.

You have to note that the scope of variables in those two types of widgets can vary. For example...

```
class ExampleStateless extends StatelessWidget {

    final String userName;
    final int points; 

   const ExampleStateless({
    @required this.userName,
    @required this.points,
   });

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context){
      print(userName); print(points);  

      return Something();
   }
}
```

Note that for the stateful widget, there are two classes and each class has its scope. The superclass `ExampleStateful` can share its scope to its subclass `_ExampleStatefulState` via the `widget`

```
class ExampleStateful extends StatefulWidget {
    final String userName;
    final int points; 
    Static final string id = "exampleState"; 

   const ExampleStatefull({
    @required this.userName,
    @required this.points,
   });
   // scope 1 
 @override
  _ExampleStatefulState createState() => _ExampleStatefulState();
}

class _ExampleStatefulState extends State<ExampleStateful>{
  // scope 2 

 final String userName2 = null;

@override
void initState(){
   super.initState();
   print(widget.userName);
   print(userName2);
   print(ExampleStateful.id);  // you can do this only if variable is static. 
 }
}
```

What is in scope 1 can be accessed in scope 2 via the widget properties. eg `print(widget.userName);` instead of print(userName);